# command for jupyter lab not found after installing with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-lab

I tried to install a package with `python3 -m pip install package` but it says some of the script has been installed in `/home/name/.local/bin` **which is not on PATH.** And when I try to run them it says that Command `X` not found.

What should I do now? and more important, what is the better way to solve this? thanks.

The output of `which python3` is `/usr/bin/python3`

The output of echo `$PATH` is

```sh
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What OS and what specific package did you install?

Comment: @GinoMempin ubuntu 20.04 / i tried to install jupyterlab

Comment: what happens when pip install jupyter-notebook ?

Comment: @BuddhikaBandara I want to install jupyterlab not notebook. but i got a same result with pip3 install jupyterlab. so i think it's more about the PATH

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-python-command-not-found/

Answer (score 1):

You would just need to add `/home/name/.local/bin` to your PATH environmental variable. To do so:

```
export PATH="/home/name/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

You can also add this line to `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, etc (depending on your shell and OS) to make the change permanently.

Comment: @daan It's actually mentioned in the [jupyterlab pip installation docs](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html#pip) that you need to do this: "*If installing using `pip install --user`, you must add the user-level `bin` directory to your `PATH` environment variable in order to launch `jupyter lab`.*"